# Sum of Recycler View Items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my iteration i have no idea how to do that.
i want to get a sum of total variable defined in bind view holder and display the sum in my activity's text-box. Increasing and Decreasing functionality are working perfectly fine.

```
  @Override
    public CartAdapter.VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new VH(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_recycler_items, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CartAdapter.VH holder, int position) {

        final MultipleCartWrapper entity = multipleCartWrapperArrayList.get(position);
        holder.itemquantity.setText(entity.getQuantity());
        holder.itemname.setText(entity.getFood().getName());
        holder.itemprice.setText(entity.getFood().getPrice()+"");
        int quan = Integer.parseInt(holder.itemquantity.getText().toString());
        int price = (int) Float.parseFloat(holder.itemprice.getText().toString());
        total = String.valueOf(quan*price);
        holder.total.setText(total);
        holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int quan = Integer.parseInt(holder.itemquantity.getText().toString());
                int price = (int) Float.parseFloat(holder.itemprice.getText().toString());
                quan++;
                String quantity = String.valueOf(quan);
                holder.itemquantity.setText(quantity);
                String total = String.valueOf(quan*price);
                holder.total.setText(total);
        }});
             holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int quan = Integer.parseInt(holder.itemquantity.getText().toString());
                int price = (int) Float.parseFloat(holder.itemprice.getText().toString());
                if (quan >=1){
                    quan--;
                    String quantity = String.valueOf(quan);
                    holder.itemquantity.setText(quantity);
                    String total = String.valueOf(quan*price);
                    holder.total.setText(total);
 } }}); }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return multipleCartWrapperArrayList.size();
    }
```

I want to do one thing more that when ever i increase or decrease some item the value of total price should change in the total text-box. Please give me the solution. I shall be very grateful to you.

Comment: That's a weird place to try to sum up data. Your RecyclerView is populated based on a List, correct? Can't you sum up all the prices in the same place where you fetch the List?

Comment: @Gavin Wright is correct. And the you can just listen to onClick on your increase or decrease button of item and manipulate the total sum accordingly.